# How to run Thunderbird in the background?

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, notification, webapps, gmail

I want to get instant notifications for new emails and I don't want to install and configure an extra program for that. Thunderbird shows notifications, so does Gmail webapp. But both of them work only as long as they are open and running (or minimized).

Is there a way to have Thunderbird show notifications without keeping it open (at least the GUI)?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks

Comment: There is this addon which seems to do exaclty that : https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/keeprunning/

Answer (score 14):

I recommend (and use) FireTray, which you can get at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/firetray/.

It will keep Thunderbird running in the background, and then notify you of new emails.

Comment: The latest version is from 2016, and only works with Thunderbird 7.0 - 50.0

Comment: Yes, FireTray is no longer supported by new versions of Thunderbird. I've not used Thunderbird in a while now, so I unfortunately don't know of any alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

As **FireTray** is not supporting the **Thunderbird** version **68+**
You can get still receive emails in background by using another trustfull Ubuntu app named as **Geary** 
(I am also using it).
So to install Geary, use the below command -

```
sudo apt install geary
```

That's it.
Now open it and do the formalties saying by geary and then
 go to `preferences`, check the checkbox named as [✔] **Watch for new mail when closed**.
You have all done here.
Enjoy !

Comment: Can it change the size or zooming? My font-size is too small but I can't find the font size or zooming in Geary.

Comment: Yes you can change the font-size in _Geary_ with the **keyboard shortcut**  `ctrl+` , `ctrl-`, `ctrl0` for increase, decrease and reset the font-size. Now whenever you open 
 geary in future it will continue to use the changed font-size.

Comment: See all **keyboard Shortcuts** of geary to work fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use minimize to tray add-on; TB needs to start though. See [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-revived/) link for description and downloading

Comment: Tried the extension. Still not getting notifications. I gave up on Thunderbird for now

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `Birdtray` package. It works really great.

```
sudo apt install birdtray
```

https://linux-packages.com/ubuntu-jammy-jellyfish/package/birdtray

Answer (score 0):

On Kubuntu 20.04, I've just installed :

- kdocker packet : start it and click on Thunderbird main window title, it will go to the systray.
- extension [minimize-on-close](https://addons.thunderbird.net/fr/thunderbird/addon/minimize-on-close/) to just minimize on close (and so go to systray with kdocker)

That works perfectly and takes 1 minute to install both.

Answer (score 0):

FireTray plugin does not work with the recent versions of Thunderbird.

One workaround is to make the application automatically run at startup.

Go to -> System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications

Then set `name` as Thunderbird and `command` as `thunderbird`

Then click Add.

Answer (score 0):

In thunderbird's settings there's actually one setting that could interest you:
In Swedish it's named `När Thunderbird minimeras, flytta den till aktivitetsfält`, which means something like "When Thunderbird is minimized, move it to system tray".
If you close Thunderbird it will be gone until you start it again but if you minimize it it will close the window and appear in the system tray.
I found this setting in Thunderbird 102.3.3, it's probably there for a while.