# Thunderbird: sync in background (no gui)

Tags: thunderbird

Is it possible to keep Thunderbird running in the background (no gui) s it can stay in sync and display notifications in the messages menu?

Yes I have checked this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471782/how-to-run-thunderbird-in-the-background?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

There are [Firetray](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/firetray/) and ['MinimizeToTray revived'](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-revived/?src=ss), both of which seem to be no longer maintained. However Firetray works for me with TB 38.6 and Plasma 5.5.4

Comment: Yes I did check them and as you mention they are discontinued. I don't want to depend on that. Moreover, it's weird if we cannot run Thunderbird from the terminal without a gui.