# How can I make firefox run in the background like chromium?

Tags: firefox, chromium, window-manager, minimize, background-process

A known feature in Chromium is the option to make it run in the background, which makes it easier to open .

Is it possible to do the same with firefox (and other applications)?

Comment: Please define "in the background". Without a window?

Comment: Yes without a window (Like uGet and Telegram)

Comment: I see, can be done. Will post back if no one does before I do :)

Comment: No one answered :(

Comment: Haha, no, but it needs some work to create the solution. I will probably post tomorrow :)

Comment: Ok thank you for all your effort .
Just wondering if it is difficult ?

Comment: Do you want something like this add-on? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/minimizetotray-revived/  Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/471782/how-to-run-thunderbird-in-the-background/472423#472423

Comment: @muru did you try? It does.. well, totally nothing but close the application. Just like the comments mention.

Comment: @muru 
It does nothing !
The only solution is provided in the answer below by Magnificent Jacob

Comment: @JacobVlijm I used to use it months ago. Haven't tried it recently.

Comment: @muru Ah, thanks. Also: In case anyone tried the linked add-on, it leaves firefox with a pid, but no traceable windows. Please run `killall firefox` before running the answer below, else the script will assume firefox runs already.  (you might want to remove the comment :) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Running an application in the background

The solution below will allow you to run firefox (or any other application) in the background, meaning: *without a visible window*. Nor will the application show in Dash as a running application:

[image]

[image]

If you pick <kbd>Toggle Firefox</kbd> however, the application will pop up immediately:

[image]

#### How it works

1. If the panel icon (indicator) starts up, it launches a new `firefox` window, but immediately hides it (including possible existing `firefox` windows) from the face of the earth, using `xdotool`:

   ```
   xdotool windowunmap <window_id>
   ```

   This will not only hide the window, but also will hide the fact that `firefox` is running *at all*, since the unity launcher acts on visibly existing windows.
2. The indicator stores the id of all unmapped windows in `~/.config/hidden_windows`, to be mapped on the next time you choose <kbd>Toggle Firefox</kbd> from the menu.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3
import time

app = "firefox"
winsdir = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], ".config/hidden_windows")

try:
    os.mkdir(winsdir)
except FileExistsError:
    pass

def checkruns(app):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", app]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        for w in os.listdir(winsdir):
            if w.startswith(app):
                os.remove(os.path.join(winsdir, w))

def get_currentwins(pid):
    wins = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
    return [l.split()[0] for l in wins if pid in l]

def hide_currentwins(matches):
    # open(os.path.join(winsdir, "windowlist"), "wt").write("\n".join(matches))
    for w in matches:
        open(os.path.join(winsdir, app+"_"+w), "wt")
        subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "windowunmap", w])

def run_app(app):
    subprocess.Popen(app)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        pid = checkruns(app)
        matches = get_currentwins(pid) if pid else None
        if matches:
            hide_currentwins(matches)
            break

def restore_wins():
    for w in [w for w in os.listdir(winsdir) if w.startswith(app)]:
        wid = w.split("_")[-1]
        subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "windowmap", wid])
        os.remove(os.path.join(winsdir, w))

def toggle_app(*args):
    pid = checkruns(app)
    if pid:
        matches = get_currentwins(pid)
        if matches:
            hide_currentwins(matches)
        else:
            restore_wins()
    else:
        subprocess.Popen(app)

run_app(app)

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'toggle_app'
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, app,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())

    def create_menu(self):
        self.menu = Gtk.Menu()
        item_toggle = Gtk.MenuItem('Toggle '+app)
        item_toggle.connect("activate", toggle_app)
        self.menu.append(item_toggle)
        sep1 = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        self.menu.append(sep1)
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        self.menu.append(item_quit)
        self.menu.show_all()
        return self.menu

    def stop(self, source):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `firefox_bg.py`
3. Test_run the script by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/firefox_bg.py
   ```
4. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && python3 /path/to/firefox_bg.py"
   ```

   Alternatively, copy the code below into an empty file, save it as `firefox_bgrunner.desktop` in `~/usr/share/applications`, log out and back in.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec=python3 /path/to/firefox_bg.py
   Name=Firefox Webbrowser Background Runner
   Icon=firefox
   StartupWMClasss=nonsense
   ```

   *The last line, `StartupWMClasss=nonsense` is to make sure `Firefox windows will appear under their own icon, not the one of the indicator`.

   No need to mention that you have to edit the `Exec=` line to reflect the real (absolute) path to where you stored `firefox_bg.py`

   Then you will have the panel runner available from Dash:

   [image]

#### Other applications?

I tested the same procedure with `gnome-terminal` and`Thunderbird` (the latter usually not the quickest to startup), and it works perfectly:

[image]

To use with other applications, simply edit the line:

```
app = "firefox"
```

***Note*** however that some applications seem to check if their attempt to create a window succeeded, and create a second one if the first one is unmapped. This happened to me with `Inkscape`.

The script can even then perfectly be used though, but would need a small edit. If anyone ever might need to use it with `Inkscape`, please leave a comment.

Comment: WOW !!!
Can't beleive it !
It works just like that :) :) 
Thanks a lot 
You are awesome <3

Comment: @akkk3 Thanks! it was fun to do :)

Comment: Is it technically possible to have this as a Gnome Extension?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose a 2019 solution to this for Ubuntu 18-19+ with GNOME that is a little bit simpler (IMO) and uses bash instead of python for simplicity. I made this so that Firefox would ask for my Master Password when I signed in, but then not ask again unless I went to view passwords. I was tired of it popping up every time I started firefox.

First install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y wmctrl xdotool
```

Then put this script somewhere, say `/data/system/bin/firefox-background`:

```
firefox "about:blank" &
WAITFOR="Mozilla Firefox"

APP=$(wmctrl -lp |grep "${WAITFOR}" |awk '{print $1}')
while [ -z "${APP}" ]; do
    sleep 1
    APP=$(wmctrl -lp |grep "${WAITFOR}" |awk '{print $1}')
done
xdotool windowunmap ${APP}
```

And:

```
chmod +x /data/system/bin/firefox-background
```

Now you can run this script however you would like such as from a terminal window or from the GNOME startup with a file in `.config/autostart/FirefoxBackground.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Background
Exec=/data/system/bin/firefox-background
Terminal=false
Icon=firefox
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
StartupWMClasss=nonsense
```

After that, you'll get a popup for the master password once, and never again unless you intend to access secure info.