# How to open Thunderbird minimised at startup in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, thunderbird, lts

I looked around for a solution that still works in 16.04. I found that previously offered [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169437/how-to-start-thunderbird-minimized-on-start-up) including the one which was accepted were for older versions of Ubuntu.

The results were Thunderbird would open but not minimised.

There are alternative solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663187/how-can-i-run-a-program-on-startup-minimized) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853891/how-can-i-make-firefox-run-in-the-background-like-chromium/854163#854163) that explain ways to do this, they are general purpose scripts which can be adapted. However, it's a bit complex for the task and not tailored to Thunderbird.

Comment: There are at least two good (working) options for 16.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/663187/how-can-i-run-a-program-on-startup-minimized/663288#663288 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/853891/how-can-i-make-firefox-run-in-the-background-like-chromium/854163#854163 I will link the first one as a dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I achieved the desired behaviour in the following way:

**1)** Install `alltray` which provides an easy method to open Thunderbird at startup:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install alltray
```

**2)** Add to Startup Applications:

[image: Startup Applications]

This will open Thunderbird at startup but it will not be minimised.

**----- UPDATE** `Minimize on Start and Close` **IS NO LONGER SUPPORTED -----**

<s>**3)** Then install `Minimize on Start and Close` in Thunderbird (Tools->Add-ons->Get Add-ons)</s>

This needs to be configured (Tools->Add-ons->Extensions->Preferences) as follows:

[image: Add-on Config]

**--------------------------------------------------**

**3)** Then install `Keep in Taskbar` and restart Thunderbird.

This is a combination of previous suggestions from various locations that works in Ubuntu 16.04.

**I thought I would share this to provide an easy, updated method for others.**

Comment: Ah, I just see now it's an answer to your own question :), nice!

Comment: I know there are other, more general purpose solutions out there. This method is a combination of various sources and it seems to be a bit more simple as it's specific to Thunderbird. Thought others might find it useful if it were put together in one place.

Comment: Nice option, upvoted!

Comment: Not working on Ubuntu 18.04